# How to reduce the number of bits in the programmer calculator on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

How do I reduce the number of bits from 64 to 8 bits on the Mac OS Programmer calculator?

[image: Mac OSX 64 bit programmer calculator]

Comment: Do you just want to reduce the displayed bits or do you want to get a calculator which wrapps around after reaching 2^8?

Comment: @nohillside I want to wrap around 2^8 including signed numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't seem to be any options to limit the display to only show 8 bits.

Sorry.